# Deleting specific div with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, session

I'm making a To do application in PHP for a school assignment.

At this point, I can add new tasks. But the problem is:

- When I click at a div (to delete it), the div is deleted, **BUT all the other tasks get invisible**. They only show up again if I create a new task.

This is my code

File `Index.php`

```
<div class="container">

<form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
<div class="headerToDo">
    <input class="addText title" type="text" value="Click to add a task" name="nextToDo">
    <input class="clickablePlus" type="submit" value="+" name="submit"></div>
</form>

<?php if(!$empty): ?>
<?php foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $_SESSION["key"] => $toDo): ?>
<div class="toDo">
    <form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">

        <button value="<?php echo $_SESSION["key"] ?>" name="delete" class="delete" type="submit" >X</button>
        <button value="<?php echo $_SESSION["key"] ?>" name="done" class="done" type="submit" >V</button>
        <div value="<?php echo $_SESSION["key"] ?>" class="textToDo"><?= $toDo ?></div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Application.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS["empty"] = true;

$_SESSION['todoList'] = isset($_SESSION['todoList']) ? $_SESSION['todoList'] : array();


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $empty = false;
    array_unshift($_SESSION['todoList'], $_POST["nextToDo"]);
}

if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
    unset($_SESSION['todoList'][$_SESSION["key"]]);
    //var_dump($key);
}

?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $_SESSION["key"] => $toDo)` that line looks weird to me. Each iteration you assign a new value to `$_SESSION["key"]`. At the end of execution, `$_SESSION["key"]` will contain the last seen value. Is it what you want to do? Could you tell us what `$_SESSION["key"]` and `$_SESSION["todoList"]` are supposed to contain?

Comment: '$_SESSION["key"]' is ment for an unique number for each div so I could find out which div was clicked. 

'$_SESSION["todoList"]' should contain all the added tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to handle it like a normal post, since this key will be available on submission:

```
<!-- no need to create every form -->
<form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
<?php foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $key => $toDo): ?>
    <div class="toDo">
        <button value="<?php echo $key; ?>" name="delete" class="delete" type="submit" >X</button>
        <button value="<?php echo $key; ?>" name="done" class="done" type="submit" >V</button>
        <div value="<?php echo $key; ?>" class="textToDo"><?= $toDo ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Then, upon submission:

```
if(isset($_POST["delete"])) {
    $key = $_POST["delete"];
    unset($_SESSION['todoList'][$key]);
}
```

Sidenote: Are you sure your form action is `/Periodeopdracht/index.php`? Maybe this operation is intended to use `Application.php` like you posted the `$_POST` processes above.

Also, this is superfluous/unneeded.

```
$_SESSION['todoList'] = isset($_SESSION['todoList']) ? $_SESSION['todoList'] : array();
```

This reassignment makes no sense.

Just use a simple initialization:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['todoList'])) {
    $_SESSION['todoList'] = array();
}
```

A Little bit of rewrite:

Form:

```
<div class="container">

    <form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
    <div class="headerToDo">
        <input class="addText title" type="text" value="Click to add a task" name="nextToDo">
        <input class="clickablePlus" type="submit" value="+" name="submit"></div>
    </form>

    <!-- no need to create every form -->
    <form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
        <?php foreach($_SESSION["todoList"] as $key => $toDo): ?>
            <div class="toDo">
                <button value="<?php echo $key; ?>" name="delete" class="delete" type="submit" >X</button>
                <button value="<?php echo $key; ?>" name="done" class="done" type="submit" >V</button>
                <div class="textToDo"><?php echo $toDo; ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </form>

</div>
```

Then in `/Periodeopdracht/index.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

// simple initialization
if(!isset($_SESSION['todoList'])) {
    $_SESSION['todoList'] = array();
}

// addition / push inside items
if(isset($_POST["submit"], $_POST["nextToDo"])) {
    $_SESSION['todoList'][] = $_POST["nextToDo"];
}

// delete key
if(isset($_POST["delete"])) {
    $key = $_POST["delete"];
    unset($_SESSION['todoList'][$key]);
}

?>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew you could get the key with '$key = $_POST["delete"];' 

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @RW24 yes this will be available since you submitted your form. im glad this helped

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean with your sidenote.

Comment: @RW24 my sidenote was referring to the conflict between `Application.php` and `/Periodeopdracht/index.php`. i do not know the reason why `Application.php` was there in your question.

Comment: It's because the PHP logic is there. (I include application.php) in my index.php 

Is that a wrong way?

Comment: @RW24 oh okay so it was included it was just a naming issue okay no prob im glad this helped